# Hadoop/Pig regular expression matching

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

This is kind of an odd situation, but I'm looking for a way to filter using something like MATCHES but on a list of unknown patterns (of unknown length).

That is, if the given input is two files, one with numbers A:

xxxx

yyyy

zzzz

zzyy

...etc...

And the other with patterns B:

xx.*

yyy.*

...etc...

How can I filter the first input, by all of the patterns in the second?

If I knew all the patterns beforehand, I could
A = FILTER A BY (num MATCHES 'somepattern.*' OR num MATCHES 'someotherpattern'....);

The problem is that I don't know them beforehand, and since they're patterns and not simple strings, I cannot just use joins/groups (at least as far as I can tell).
Maybe a strange nested FOREACH...thing?
Any ideas at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `|` which operates as an `OR` you can construct a pattern out of the individual patterns.

```
(xx.*|yyy.*|zzzz.*)
```

This will do a check to see if it matches any of the patterns.

Edit:
To create the combined regex pattern:
* Create a string starting with `(`
* Read in each line (assuming each line is a pattern) and append it to a string followed by a `|`
* When done reading lines, remove the last character (which will be an unneeded `|`)
* Append a `)`

This will create a regex pattern to check all the patterns in the input file. (Note: It's assumed the file contains valid patterns)

Comment: How can that be done programmatically?  As I said, I have no knowledge of how many of these patterns there are (or their contents, obviously) beforehand.

Comment: @SubSevn: Updated the post with logic

Comment: So there's no way to do this with straight Pig?

Comment: @SubSevn: I'm not familiar with Pig so I can't say how to implement the solution in that specifically.  You might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285082/regexp-matching-in-pig and see if that helps point you in a useful direction.

Comment: Ahhhh, well that's what the issue is: Pig appears to be fairly incomplete.  Unfortunately, I'm somewhat constrained to that...

Comment: @SubSevn: I haven't used PIG or streaming at all, but checking into streaming might allow you to utilize python or another language to do the filtering and then return to a PIG script? ... Just an idea, since I haven't used those, just have some familiarity with the concepts.

Comment: I plan on creating a UDF in Pig to do what you're saying, read in the inputs and then combine them into a single regex, then I can just use "blah = FILTER somestuff BY x MATCHES regex" and be done with it.  Thanks!